# Issue while filtering in object with react

Tags: reactjs

the code updates the searchfield but when i use it with another
function for its not working.

the below line shows the value in console,
console.log(this.state.seachfield,'seachfield')
but doesn't work in filterRobots.

the filterRobots works 
if i use event.target.value instead of this.state.searchfield.

```
//imports 
import React , {Component}from 'react';
import {robots} from './robots';
import CardList from './CardList';
import Searchbox from './Searchbox';

//main app
class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      robots : robots,
      searchfield : ""
    }
  }
  //the on change event, update searcfield.
  OnSearchChange =(event) =>{
     this.setState({seachfield : event.target.value})
}

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.seachfield, 'seachfield');
    //filter by name
    const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robot =>{
      return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield)
      })
      console.log(filteredRobots);


    return(
      <div className="tc">
        <h1> Robots Title </h1>
        <Searchbox searchchange={this.OnSearchChange}/>
        <CardList robots={filteredRobots}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: The problem within your `Searchbox`

Comment: `seachfield` vs `searchfield`, `OnSearchChange` should be `onSearchChange` - or can be recognized as functional component

Comment: thanks @xadm for pointing out the error.